# TypeScript function property of object parameter interface ... any number of args

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a function declaration in an `Interface` like this:

```
mixin(desc: MixinDescriptor): any;
```

The `MixinDescriptor` is defined like this:

```
interface MixinDescriptor { [id: string]: () => any; }
```

However, if I use the `mixin` function like this:

```
chance.mixin({
  test: function(arg1, arg2) {
  }
}
```

VSCode will indicate that it's not the right definition. It works, because its implementation works like that, but its interface declaration has to be wrong.

I've tried changing the `MixinDescriptor` to this:

```
interface MixinDescriptor { [id: string]: (args: any[]) => any; }
```

But that didn't work either.

How might I change that so it properly identifies the functions as able to accept named parameters, any number of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 interface MixinDescriptor { 
     [id: string]: (...args: any[]) => any; 
 }
```

`...` indicate that function can take the [rest of parameters](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-rest-parameters). Since rest parameters is optional this interface applies for any kind of function

Also consider [this example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20MixinDescriptor%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%5Bid%3A%20string%5D%3A%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20any%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20abc(take%3A%20MixinDescriptor)%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabc(%7B%0D%0A%09taketake%3Afunction(a%2C%20b%2C%20c%2C%20d)%7B%0D%0A%09%09%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D)%3B)

Comment: Ironically, in other answers that I looked at, I thought that was the defacto `...` indicating code that wasn't relevant. Hopefully this helps somebody in the same way in the future. Good answer!